# Porquê não posso criar uma chave IPC com o arquivo ~/.bashrc?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

Estava a resolver alguns exercícios da escola e no enunciado havia uma questão:

> Pode-se gerar uma chave IPC com o arquivo .bashrc?

Eu não sabendo a resposta para questão, criei um programa em C que tenta fazer exatamente o mesmo:

```
if((key = ftok("~/.bashrc",'A'))<0)
{
    printf("A resposta e não.\n") 
    exit(-1);
}
```

E a resposta é mesmo não. Mas porquê?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vejamos...

Se você **trocar o `~`**:

```
"~/.bashrc"
```

... **Por um caminho absoluto**:

```
"/home/meu_usuario/.bashrc"
```

... **Vai funcionar** normalmente!

### Exemplo

Tomando meu usuário como `jose`, tem-se o código abaixo (em C):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main( void ) {

    key_t key;

    if( ( key = ftok( "/home/jose/.bashrc",'A' ) ) < 0 ) {

        printf("Não.\n");

        exit(-1);

        } else printf("Sim.\n");

    return(0);

    }
```

... Que gera a seguinte saída depois de compilado e executado:

```
[jose@poseidon ˜]$ gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror programa.c -o exe
[jose@poseidon ˜]$ ./exe
Sim.
[jose@poseidon ˜]$ ./exe
```

### Explicação

Note que em C é possível usar caminhos relativos bem como o próprio `~`. Porém o `~`, que expande ao diretório do seu usuário, sempre causa problemas pois ele só expande se for o primeiro caractere do `path` fornecido.

[Dentro de aspas duplas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151865/55534), além de não ser o primeiro caractere, todos os caracteres são lidos sem poderes especiais - com exceção de `$`, de **`**, de `\` e de `@`.

Existem [algumas soluções](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7163364/1494516) diferentes e a oficial POSIX para expansões shell com [wordexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15991337/1494516). Mas o melhor é colocar o caminho absoluto se for algo simples e direto como no exemplo acima.